# Run a polymer command like `polymer help`, it always throws an error

Tags: polymer

I am trying to follow polymer tutorial: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/start/toolbox/set-up

When I run a polymer command like `polymer help`, it allways throws the following error:

```
C:\(...)\npm\node_modules\polymer-cli\bin\polymer.js:19   
  let lib = path ? require(path) : require('..');                                 
  ^^^                                                                             
SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word                                 
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)                                     
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)                                         
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)                           
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)                                             
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)                                   
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)                                 
    at startup (node.js:129:16)                                                   
    at node.js:814:3
```

I already reinstalled Polymer cli, but it returns allways the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

I reinstalled node js and now I can run Polymer.
Maybe I had an unsuported version of node js.